# How do i create a conditional query in mongoose

Tags: jquery, database, mongodb, mongoose, mern

In laravel we create a conditional query and can implement later.

```
use App\Http\Models\User

$user = new User;
$query = $user->find("foo");
$result = $query->getPostByUser();
```

In Mongoose, i tried this way, but *query* reuturn a executed result.

```
import User from "../Models/User.js";

const query = await Post.find(
    {
        foo: "bar"
    }
);
const Post = await query.limit(5);
```

How can i create a conditonal query in mongoose like in laravel.

Answer (score 2):

all mongoose model's methods will return query and then you need to execute your query with either `await` or `.exec()` so try this:

```js
    const query = Post.find({foo: "bar"});
    const post = await query.limit(5);
```

Comment: I also want to use *query* form multiple times. For Eample:
`const query = Post.find({foo: "bar"});
    const post = await query.limit(5);
const count = await query.countDocuments();`

Comment: @LeoJames that's possible too

Comment: But I execute second times, it responses "*query* is already executed" error.

Comment: that's because you have already executed the query in `const post = await query.limit(5);` instead do this `const query = Post.find({foo: "bar"}); const post = query.limit(5); const count = await query.countDocuments();`

Comment: In this case, I want to get both value of *post* and *count*.

Comment: then you need to either make another query of the same query or clone it. and then execute both queries to get `post` and `count`

Comment: Actually I'm trying to refactor my code. Because *query* in my code is longer than in this example code, I don't want to repeat that long code.
Is there any anyway to refactor my code in this case.